# Activeadmin: disable pagination when exporting xml/json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, export, activeadmin

How can I disable pagination for json/xml export in activeadmin? I could't figure out any solution for this. I'm getting only current page when hitting export to xml or json.

Answer (score 2):

One solution (no the best) is disable de pagination with a before_filter

```
controller do
  before_filter :disable_pagination, :only => [:index]

  def disable_pagination
    @per_page = YourModel.count
  end
end
```

This make a pagination with only one page for all the records, so it is going to export all the records.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done like this,

```
controller do
    def index
      super do |format|
        per_page = (request.format == 'text/html') ? 30 : 10_000 # to skip the pagination
        params[:page] = nil unless (request.format == 'text/html') #It will be working even after we export the CSV on the paginated sections.
        @users = @users.order("first_name asc, last_name asc").page(params[:page]).per(per_page)
        @users ||= end_of_association_chain.paginate if @users.present?
      end
    end
end
```